# Split one video file into small files made up of its scenes

Tags: premiere, editing

I'm trying to come up with a workflow to take completed short films, and split them up into individual files based on where each shot that makes up the film starts and ends.

I've used the scene detection feature in Adobe SpeedGrade to figure out where shots should start and end, but I'm having trouble taking that information and actually rendering out individual shots based on it. I had expected to be able to bring this info back into Premiere Pro using an EDL (Edit Decision List) but none of the "cuts" that SpeedGrade marked seem to be reflected when I try this. Either I'm doing something wrong or Premiere/SpeedGrade can't support this sort of workflow.

Also to keep in mind, this is expected to be a repetitive process, and I'm developing this workflow for people who may be inexperienced in video editing, so it really should be automated as much as possible. Manually entering the start and end times of each shot isn't really a viable option because it would be ridiculously time consuming, even after SpeedGrade determines these times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workflow I decided to use. It's a little slower than what I had hoped, but it seems to fit my needs.

1. Convert videos into MOV or AVI
2. Import into SpeedGrade
3. Run Scene Detect
4. Manually confirm correct scene detection.
5. Export each shot individually from Speed Grade
6. Convert to a web-ready MP4 using Media Encoder (MP4 is required in my use case but it might not be in everyone's)

Some background--apparently EDL's with 'dumb cuts' (i.e. cuts where the video before and after the cut is from the same clip) aren't recognized in most video editors, so importing the EDL into premiere won't work for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

For AVI-Files there is a little program that can help you split your file into scenes: http://www.avcutty.de/english/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DV Rebel Tools](http://stumaschwitz.com/store/dvrg) by Stu Maschwitz. It comes with a script for AE to split a single video file into layers based on scene changes. From AE, you should be able to send this to premiere pro for mastering individual layers.